# Future Builder for using Json response on map

Tags: json, flutter, dart, maps

I am calling an API and utilising the return Json data to post markers on a map

I have the Call returning a ListView fine on a separate application

I tried to implement my Future builder from my other application calling the same HTTP, with some modifications.

I am now getting errors from the Future Builder construction after trying to implement a Future Builder, which I have been told will fix the previous error as it is mandatory, to the best of my beginners ability!

I am pulling the `stations.place.location.lat` & `stations.place.location.lng` Json to use in GeoCoordinates to place the marker from my API call

Here is the Dart code I am using, any guidance is appreciated. I will exclude code which is irrelevant to this issue.

The Future Builder (of which there is some rough code left in my example below) needs to go into my Main.dart

```
void main() {
  SdkContext.init(IsolateOrigin.main);

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget { 

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
 

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Future<Stations> stations;
  


  @override
  void initState() {
    stations = API_Call().fetchStations(); 
   super.initState();
  }
    BuildContext _context;
  MapMarkerExample _mapMarkerExample; 
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _context = context;
    

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Example 1'),
        ),
        
      body:  Container(
        child: 

FutureBuilder<Stations>(
          future: stations,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Stations> snapshot) {
          
          if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
           else

           
          return Stack(
          children: [
            HereMap(onMapCreated: _onMapCreated),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    button('Call', _anchoredMapMarkersButtonClicked),
                    button('Clear', _clearButtonClicked),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        );
        }
        );
        }
        }
        )
      )
      )
    );
  }
...
```

api_manager.dart

```
class MapMarkerExample{
 
    
 void showAnchoredMapMarkers() {
  var stations;
 
        stations = API_Call().fetchStations(); 
       for (Station stations in stations) {
           GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = GeoCoordinates (stations.place.location.lat, stations.place.location.lng);
         
           }

           GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = stations.coordinates;
           _addPOIMapMarker(geoCoordinates, 1);
 
    }
...
```

api_call.dart

```
class API_Call {
  
Future<Stations> fetchStations() async {
    var client = http.Client();

      final response = await client.get(
      'https://transit.hereapi.com/v8/stations?in=x,-x&return=transport&apiKey=MY_API_KEY');
   
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Stations.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)); 
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load stations');
  }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your service is returning a list, you should handle it as List.

> ```
>     List<Station> stations = [];
>     final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
>     stations = responseData.map((model) => Station.fromJson(model)).toList();
> ```

And don't forget the itemLength value for ListView.builder()

Comment: Thanks, the thing is I don't think I'm unsure if I need a list builder at all, but don't know what to put in its place as i am not displaying the data on the screen in a list form, it is being taken immediately and used in a separate sequence, the 'Void' to build the marker?